# In R, how can I compute the summary function in parallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, nnet

I have a huge dataset. I computed the multinomial regression by multinom in nnet package.

```
mylogit<- multinom(to ~ RealAge, mydata)
```

It takes 10 minutes. But when I use summary function to compute the coefficient
it takes more than 1 day!!!
This is the code I used:

```
output <- summary(mylogit) 

Coef<-t(as.matrix(output$coefficients))
```

I was wondering if anybody know how can I compute this part of the code by parallel processing in R?

this is a small sample of data:

```
mydata:
to  RealAge
513 59.608
513 84.18
0   85.23
119 74.764
116 65.356
0   89.03
513 92.117
69  70.243
253 88.482
88  64.23
513 64
4   84.03
65  65.246
69  81.235
513 87.663
513 81.21
17  75.235
117 49.112
69  59.019
20  90.03
```

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data where the time to get the summary is larger than the time to fit the model?

Comment: Yes, I added a small sample data for your consideration

Comment: What is `out` and `FinalData`? Moreover, your example will be too quick to see anything.

Comment: I edited my question to better understand the problem. Is it clear now for you? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try using the `coef()` method instead of the `summary()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the coefficients, use only the `coef()` method which do less computations.

Example:

```
mydata <- readr::read_table("to  RealAge
513 59.608
513 84.18
0   85.23
119 74.764
116 65.356
0   89.03
513 92.117
69  70.243
253 88.482
88  64.23
513 64
4   84.03
65  65.246
69  81.235
513 87.663
513 81.21
17  75.235
117 49.112
69  59.019
20  90.03")[rep(1:20, 3000), ]

mylogit <- nnet::multinom(to ~ RealAge, mydata)
system.time(output <- summary(mylogit))          # 6 sec
all.equal(output$coefficients, coef(mylogit))    # TRUE & super fast
```

If you profile the `summary()` function, you'll see that the most of the time is taken by the `crossprod()` function. 
So, if you really want the output of the `summary()` function, you could use an optimized math library, such as the MKL provided by [Microsoft R Open](https://mran.microsoft.com/open/).

Comment: it's too fast. Thank you so much

Comment: @SomayehGhazalbash If you are okay with this answer, you can accept it (on the left).

Comment: Is there any easy and fast code for computing p_value, too? It's much appreciated if you let me know about it.

Comment: @SomayehGhazalbash See what I said about the `summary()` function in my answer.